# Is the integer factorization into prime numbers normally distributed?

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability, prime-numbers, trees, random-permutations

**Edit**:
Sorry, for the inconvenience: I have edited the question, since there was a misconception in my thinking.

Let $P_1(n) := 1$ if $n=1$ and $\max_{q\mid n, \text{ } q\text{ prime}} q$ otherwise, denote the largest prime divisor of $n$.

Let us define some rooted trees $T_{n,m}$ for $1 \le m \le n$ by:

- $T_{n,m}$ has as root the number $m$.
- If there are primes $p$ such that $P_1(m) \le p \le \frac{n}{m}$, then the children of $m$ are $T_{n,mp}$, otherwise $m$ is a leaf.

We set $T_n := T_{n,1}$. Here is an image of $T_{20}$:

[image: T_20]

We can encode these trees as parentheses $()$ or binary words $w_n$ $10$ where $(=1$ and $)=0$. Here are some words $n$ and $w_n$:

```
1
10
2
1100
3
110100
4
11100100
5
1110010100
```

From these words only it is possible to reconstruct all prime factorizations of all numbers $1 \le m \le n$, without to have to factor any number $m$, only a check is needed if a number is prime or not.

Observing those words we see that they seem to be kind of random.
To make this more precise, I suggest separating the $1$s and $0$s from each other by permutations $\sigma$ from $S_{2n}$, where $|w_n| = 2n$. This gives us a measure of its randomness, where we define the string for example:

$$0000000000111111$$

as being separated (the zeros than the ones), whereas the string:

$$010101010101010101$$

is not separated. In [Diaconis & Graham & Knuth](https://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Ecgates/PERSI/papers/77_04_spearmans.pdf) the following distance measure for permutations is suggested:

$$T(\pi,\sigma) = n - C(\pi^{-1} \sigma), \pi,\sigma \in S_n$$

where $C$ counts the number of distinct cycles of the permutation. Using this, one can define the separation measure as for a arbitrary binary word $w$ as:

$$Z(w) = \min_{ \sigma \in S_{|w|}, \sigma \text{ separates } w} T(1,\sigma) = |w|-\max_{ \sigma \in S_{|w|}, \sigma \text{ separates } w} C(\sigma) = |w| - C^*(w)$$

where we have set: $C^*(w) := \max_{ \sigma \in S_{|w|}, \sigma \text{ separates } w}C(\sigma)$

**Question: Is it true that for $N \rightarrow \infty$ we have $Z(w_n)-2n \approx \mathbf{N}(\mu_N,\sigma_N)$ is distributed as a normal distribution with mean $\mu_N$ and standard deviation $\sigma_N$?**

[Here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFVttu2zgQfTfgf-DKWJS0dXXRF6Pa931IECwWKBDDCBSJbthKFC3KUdKv3xmK1MV2ukaMUHPjmTMXueBH8pBQyXbLBYGPOBKZpol9wk_D23MjSdJLeKn5tbLK3qhqRMWfCvEqdN1oiMh6s-WigDu4zOuCU-kT3WZNmybuwvxFlEXDJUnJ3qjWihzrhigiJDExNQWARsV8GUXmtEnYYQBcckldGJam8TU-L4m9m_g7uNbzwh-1kHSA2CPMmcGRI44h-o3I3qbbeBh-uTg2dUX0e6XeiahU3bTkmOVt3QjZ-kRok43fJ6WEL_lba87LhbWWZ3TNNJEKwyFvwGXLi6crcm0OR8A_3EEdvrJENi1BA5l9KHoMf_J3TRmb0FCWIYDhErR7dVjD10ayWZalq-VYUYT_rW4K2k2bp4Pu8bzfVQArjRUDtyja9jKtQPhBqlDq3ujOGKl9kNjMqvc7kBiLKLpTvfB0wtzpJvG3rkXKEiTOKZctGMT9QyeTSQPsO0NWh2R10lEwEe2T3WGSGoTapMn4jOmn6afk08TG4PQR-em0jw9zxQqxDm1AFZurT6dQSM2blsY-rdbKV-zCAuqWKYV124CeXUKBtvwASqhqReOLaHaUTif2V3zh18OBBJBwc4C_sYOtKDl8DDCorm8zBUxJdeMyDRcBv0FyrXpuePZz1p5Qxn28oxq3wgY7bYMS87w79E7Tzn2Qk4VnQ9j1pQRoguGsTw1OFWORxIG0I_m3LPjbpO09z8PRfeYNeeZtx2GZxSSThWvzdCvBZLauug8W1awvpxM2A1thswrTmQI7s8nkd05tXNaP4V4c_kiRBnHATh7A_yOLC-gDNht9zG-dhHFkw2KAHCfH0ln0U7RcKGWXzbB18twesIhI9jbAGca5SyZmnTSzt1zcw__PX2KIptGDGC0mJ8fkEv9-M7wz0IqOMJkj7SZnK2V2Iy6miw2fsEuT-TPY9StzTw2fvgAIl6xv15Id_Ia_8kbz9N_mzF3UB8yeN9W5zVpRQ8XeYECM-9tkHf8utqvoRXxymON8CPP3vORP7VmVHDe73XR20X6gfhz3cJDbeL9ww2LPfw5jtsbcovsgh6_bwcaCPgawu6mMBlM2_nj4M4njeWs7Mh8D5MohV24x_ArlgGlcF1PjPHfSIYrVaO00OqLbMF7L4LKow42mPS5f8hNrbOP_2QLr7Sx0z94-UCpIdvBWYm5WQGLhDOGBmrMUUN8KljlU-mtKRiNL1sokO7xS0Efo_n1I50bFaOTYLXz4wWImc6XgZdZqqhQL9UvdUYbSWz8xbBolc0et8di757lzXy6qM46WCiueyd5eF65VQPyaNSgdwlRn3yM74vm6MHujqsw7uQyqM4vAE9u8xDYvS5j0VdtatbsBYLBoGhwFo5fW4EVfhG7r701W0apiI9TVRAEMjApLlL0CfPzYoZzchLF8WHtXDgDBj8MvN1wQHLr0iJNtPw8TGGhgYfwHjC8GAw==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) is an image for the normalized "error" distribution $N=3000$:

[image: histogram_3000]

(Notice that in the image above I have not really computed $\max$ over all separating permutations but just taken one permutation given by the sorting algorithm.)

**Edit**: Maybe of help for answering the question posed above, are the following heuristic considerations: The word $w_{n+1}$ can be created from the word $w_n$ by inserting $10$ which corresponds to the number $n+1$ on some index $s_n$ of the word $w_n$ (after it's $s_n$-th character). I have collected those indices and normalized indices ($ 0 \le s_n/(2n) = s_n/|w_n| \le 1$) and plotted its distributions:

[image: distribution_of_index_3000]

[image: distribution_of_normalized_index_3500]

The first distribution on the histogram shows the smallest index of difference from word $w_n$ to word $w_{n+1}$, where the binary words are defined as in the prime factorization tree. What could possibly describe approximately this distribution? Would this description explain the normal distribution of the error function hypothesised earlier? The distribution shows the distribution of the index $0 \le s_n \le 2n = |w_n|$ which can be interpreted as follows: The word $w_{n+1}$ is created from the word $w_n$ by inserting $10$ in the index $s_n$ at the word $w_n$. The index is computed from the prime factorization of the number $n+1$. It represents the linear "place" of the number $n+1$ in the binary word $w_{n+1}$. For example we can take the word $w_4 = 11100100$ and insert $10$ after the $7$ character of $w_n$, since it corresponds to $n+1=5$: $w_5 = 1110010100$. The words $w_n$ have a structure at the beginning: Each of the ones in $11111 \ldots$ correspond to powers of two $1,2,4,8,16,\ldots$ which occur in the range $1,\cdots,n$. So it is expected that the first distribution of indices is right skewed, since shorter indices correspond to numbers divisible by $2$ and larger indices at the end of the word, where $101010101010100$ occurs, correspond to primes in the range $\sqrt{n} \le p \le n$. The second distribution  shows the normalized index of difference $s_n / |w_n|$ = $s_n/(2n)$ which is a number $0 \le s_n/(2n) \le 1$. It appears that this normalized index is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ as $N$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: When in a subscript, `q|n` and `q\mid n` yield identical results, but the former sets a bad example since it may encourage people with an imperfect grasp of LaTeX (and unfortunately most mathematicians who have been using LaTeX for years have an abominable level of understanding of why LaTeX and TeX were designed the way they were and what to do about it) to write `q|n` instead of `q\mid n` in contexts unlike subscripts and superscripts, thus: $$\begin{align} & q\mid n \\ \text{versus } & q|n \\ {} \\ & q\nmid n \\ \text{versus } & q\not | n \end{align} $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks, I will keep that in mind. I forget it all the time :-)

Comment: Is it even clear that the (suitably scaled) distribution of $Z(\sigma_{2n})$ over all words of length $2n$ converges to a normal distribution?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I do not know.